# How to create dynamic cells for Kendo grid for Angular

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-angular-ui

I have a Kendo grid in which I need different input controls in a single column depending on data. I have three scenarios:

1. If the value is `true`, checkbox should come on edit.
2. If the value is a `string` or `number`, textbox should come on edit
3. If the value is More, hyperlink should come on edit.

[image]

Please see the screenshot above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your template, where you define your columns, you can use a custom template for your cells. In this you can write some conditions to decide what to render:

```
<kendo-grid-column field="example" title="Example" width="100">
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
        <!-- You can use ngIf and/or ngSwitch here. -->
    </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

API: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/CellTemplateDirective/